не работает @router.message(Reg.name)
class Reg(StatesGroup):
    name = State()
    address = State()
    number = State()
    delivery = State()
    product = State()
    quantity = State()

@router.message(CommandStart())
async def start(message: types.Message):
    print(message.from_user.id)
    txt = (f'Добрый день! '
           'Меня зовут Травинка, я помогу Вам сделать заказ. Сейчас я '
           'задам Вам несколько вопросов,'
           'и мы сможем с Вами приступить к оформлению.')
    await message.reply(txt, reply_markup=kb.new_order)
    

async def get_name(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.set_state(Reg.name)
    await message.answer('Хорошо! Напишите, пожалуйста, Ваше имя')


@router.message(Reg.name)
async def get_address(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    # data = await state.get_data()
    await state.clear()
    await state.update_data(name=message.text)
    await state.set_state(Reg.address)
    user.append(message.text)
    await message.answer('Теперь напишите, пожалуйста, ваш адрес доставки')

Работает всё, но когда доходит до get_address лог пишет "is not handled"
Никак не могу понять почему. Единственное, до чего докопался - сам по себе декоратор router.message() не работает, если в него помещаю значение state.
Пишу на aiogram 3.13
Возможно, стоит выбрать версию постарше, где работает
Upd Я уже решил проблему, просили добавить блок кода с классом Reg

Добавьте в вопросе блок кода класса Reg
